# Cassandra CQL - Convert the release_version column in system.local table to an int

Tags: cassandra, cql, cqlsh

I am writing a query in cql that checks if the release version of Cassandra is greater than or equal to 3.11.10.

```
select * from system.local where release_version >= '3.11.10'
```

As the release_version is data type text this will not work and I cannot find a way to get a substring of this value or get a way to cast the value to an int.

I am unable to create a function for this as I cannot create a function on system tables.
I am also unable to use Java/Python etc it has to be done in cql.

I have also tried in clause in where statement but I cannot seem to put in more than one value in the in without an error:

> IN predicates on non-primary-key columns (release_version) is not yet supported

Would anyone know of a way to this or a workaround on how to get this to execute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't a way to do this natively in CQL.

If you can't execute code then at the very least you'd have to do it in a shell script. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

So the original query can work if you add the `ALLOW FILTERING` directive:

```
> SELECT cluster_name, release_version FROM system.local
  WHERE release_version >= '3.11.10' ALLOW FILTERING;

 cluster_name           | release_version
------------------------+-----------------
 Aarons 3.11.10 Cluster |         3.11.10

(1 rows)
```

Normally I wouldn't suggest `ALLOW FILTERING`, but the `system` keyspace uses the `LocalStrategy`, so queries will only go to a single node.  This should also work with comparisons like `>= '3.0'` or `>= '3.11'`, or even `< '4.0'`.

> As the release_version is data type text this will not work and I cannot find a way to get a substring of this value or get a way to cast the value to an int.

The data type isn't a show-stopper here.  The comparison here (on a string) will obviously be "ASCII-betical," as opposed to alpha[betical|numeric].  But the sort order shouldn't matter much on a table that'll only ever have one row.

**Edit**

> unable to create a function for this as I cannot create a function on system tables.

True statement.  But you can *create* a function in another keyspace, and *use* it on system tables.

> if I execute the select on a version lower than 3.11.10 (eg If i run the same select on 3.11.8 i am getting a result)

Got it.  To solve for this, you can build a function.  I was able to get this to work, but it's a little "hacky."  So I created a new user defined function called `concat311` which takes an integer and adds it as the patch-level version of the string "3.11."

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION stackoverflow.concat311 (input INT)
RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT RETURNS TEXT
LANGUAGE java AS 'return "3.11." + String.format("%02d", input);';
```

Essentially, it returns that patch-level version number as "zero padded," so it can be successfully compared to the `release_version` column value.

```
> SELECT cluster_name, release_version, stackoverflow.concat311(7) FROM system.local
  WHERE release_version > stackoverflow.concat311(7) ALLOW FILTERING;

 cluster_name           | release_version | stackoverflow.concat311(7)
------------------------+-----------------+----------------------------
 Aarons 3.11.10 Cluster |         3.11.10 |                    3.11.07

(1 rows)
```

The drawback here, is that this won't work with an equality constraint ("3.11.8" != "3.11.08"). But it will work with [greater|less]-than comparisons.

Comment: Hi Aaron, I have tried the ALLOW FILTERING previously but with the same result. the issue I am facing is that the greater than equal to in the where clause will give me an incorrect result if I execute the select on a version lower than 3.11.10 (eg If i run the same select on 3.11.8 i am getting a result)

Comment: @OliviaCronin right.  Because with a string comparison, the `8` is greater than the `1` in the `.10`.  Let me think on that a bit.

Comment: @OliviaCronin edit made.  TBH though, Erick's suggestion about using a script is probably a much cleaner solution.

Comment: I know the functions can be created but unfortunately this is not an option. The script is probably best.